# For Loop condition

Tags: c, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define all_mem (sizeof(x) /sizeof(x[0]))
int x[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

     int main(void) {
            //  printf("The condition is %d",(all_mem-2));
            int i;
                for(i=-1;i<=(all_mem-2);i++)
            {
                printf("The number is %d",i);
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

In the above code for loop is not even executing for a single time, i tried printing condition and its satisfies for loop condition. Any insights how macro expression in for loop condition is evaluated to the value less than -1?

Comment: in the signed / unsigned comparison, `i` gets converted to `0xffffffff`, which is way bigger than `all_mem - 2`. At least I think that's what's happening. Why are you starting `i` at -1? I don't think I've ever seen code that does that.

Comment: IS there nothing seen on the screen ?

Comment: @ShahrozShaikh: Since the loop condition fails immediately, you wouldn't expect anything. The program could simplify to `int main(void) { return 0; }` which would produce any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `all_mem` macro is returning a `size_t` value; integer promotion rules mean the comparison of `i <= (all_mem - 2)` is promoting `i` to a `size_t`, which means the value is huge, rather than `-1`. Try casting to ensure signed comparison:

```
for(i = -1; i <=(ssize_t)(all_mem- 2); ++i)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be an `(int)` cast?

Comment: @TomKarzes: Point. In practice, I usually use `size_t` or `ssize_t` types for my index variables to avoid the issue, so the `for` loop would remain as my answer specifies, and the declaration of `i` would change to `ssize_t i;`. Sure, `ssize_t` _could_ have problems, but in practice, user virtual memory is usually bounded at half the total memory space anyway, so it's okay to assume the array length will fit in a signed `size_t`. Of course, we know for a fact the array is tiny, so `int` overflow can't occur (pretty sure no version of C has `int` less than 5 bits :-) ).

Comment: But it won't solve the problem.  Since `i` starts at `-1`, the loop will immediately exit, exactly as OP reported.  It doesn't work.  The cast, in fact, has no effect since it's *already* a `size_t`.

Comment: @TomKarzes: You're misreading. I suggested a cast to `ssize_t` (note extra leading `s`, meaning signed `size_t`), not `size_t` (which it already was).

Comment: Oh, yes, you're absolutely right, I was misreading it.  My mistake!

Comment: @TomKarzes: :-) I suspect the ease of misreading is why many large projects coded in C choose to use a `typedef` with a more distinct name (e.g. CPython's `Py_ssize_t`, with almost no use of `size_t` itself; `Py_ssize_t` is also there because `ssize_t` is POSIX, not C standard, and not all compilers support POSIX types).

Answer (score 0):

after making a few corrections to the code, forinstance, sizeof() returns a `size_t`, not an `int`  the code worked perfectly.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define all_mem (sizeof(x) /sizeof(x[0]))

int x[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

int main(void)
{
    printf( "all_mem = %ld\n", all_mem ); // << added for debugging

    //  printf("The condition is %d",(all_mem-2));
    int i;
        for(i=-1;i<=(int)(all_mem-2);i++) // << 
        // << properly cast to int
        // otherwise compiler raises warning and unsigned comparison made
    {
        printf("The number is %d\n",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output from the above code:

```
all_mem = 10
The number is -1
The number is 0
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 3
The number is 4
The number is 5
The number is 6
The number is 7
The number is 8
```

When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.

If the above statement had been followed, then you would have seen the problem, without our help.

(for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and I also add: `-Wconversion -std=c99`)